# Yes & No answer in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make a C program where I can ask the following user yes or no questions:

```
Do you like beer? Y or N

Are you old enough? Y or N

How old are you?
```

if the user said over 18 print the message: `let's go for some beers`

but if one of the 2 first questions or the age is `N`, print: `sorry maybe next time`

I think the issue is with the If statement , perhaps I am not encapsulating the conditions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char answer;
    int age = 0 ;

    printf("Do you like beers Enter Y or N: \n");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    printf("\n so your answer is %c\n", answer);

    printf("Are you old enough to have a beer?\n");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    printf("\n so your answer is %c\n", answer);


    if (answer == 'Y') {

        printf("how old are you?\n");
        scanf(" %d", &age);

        if (age >= 18)
            printf("\n Let's go for some beers , I will pay the first round \n");

    }if else  (age < 18 && answer == 'N')
        printf("\n sorry my friend , maybe next time \n");



       // printf("You may NOT ");

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The program run the first condition, but when I run the second test
I does not give the correct answer

Comment: @Mike - There are other problems too, but you probably want `else if`, not `if else`.

Comment: @Mike fyi the proper english would be: so `your` answer is ..., Are you `old` enough (instead of `older` enough), and I will `pay` for... (paid is past tense, a.k.a already happened)

Comment: no problem, I edited your code without changing any of the important parts, so you can see what the proper grammar would be.

Comment: try start with [this](https://ideone.com/QZ2xd4)

Comment: You don't test the answer to the first question : so an old enough user that don't like beers will still gets beers !

Comment: Please post real code. The code shown does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your last if statement is only true if the user is under 18 AND said No. you want it to be either or.

Change the last if statement from

```
if else  (age < 18 && answer == 'N')
```

To:

```
  if else  (age < 18 || answer == 'N')
```

Comment: Please note that `age` is entered in `if (answer == 'Y') {..}` block.

Comment: Are you sure you're experienced enough to be giving advice Pintang? There's another much greater problem with the very line that you pointed out.

Comment: how about the braces, because I did the change , but still  show an issue about Incompatible cast

Comment: Yes I'm aware. I'm strictly answering the question simply as possible so the person asking will understand.

Comment: Did you change if else to else if? @Mike

Answer (score 3):

From your code snippet above, it looks like your else statement is formatted incorrectly (`if else` instead of `else if`). Also, since you are testing whether or not *either* question was false, you should use the `||` operand. So you would want to do something like:

```
else if  (age < 18 || answer == 'N')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable "answer". So, when you enter the answer to the second question it replace the first answer.

```
    int main(){

        char answer;
        char answer2;
        int age = 0 ;

        printf("Do you like beers Enter Y or N: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);
        printf("\n so you answer is %c\n", answer);

        printf("Are you older enough to have a beer?\n");
        scanf(" %c", &answer2);
        printf("\n so you answer is also %c\n", answer2);


        if (answer == 'Y' && answer2 == 'Y') {

            printf("how old are yo.\n");
            scanf(" %d", &age);

            if (age >= 18)
                printf("\n lets go for some beers , I will paid the first round \n");

        }

        else if  (answer == 'N' || answer2 == 'N')
            printf("\n sorry my friend , maybe next time \n");

           // printf("You may NOT ");

      return 0;

    }
```

Hope this is what you needed. Cheers.

Comment: What gets printed if the user likes beers and says they're old enough, but their age is under 18?

Comment: @BobJarvis ehmm I didn't thinked about that, but you have to add an else below "  if (age >= 18) " and print "sorry my friend , maybe next time "

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can think that the structure of your program is roughly as follows.

```
REPLY = PROMPT(Q1_MESSAGE)
IF(REPLY == YES){
    //Narrow down the conditions
    REPLY = PROMPT(Q2_MESSAGE)
    IF(REPLY == YES){
        //Narrow down the conditions
        REPLY = PROMPT(Q3_MESSAGE)
        IF(REPLY >= 18){
            DISPLAY(GOOD_MESSAGE)
        } ELSE {
            DISPLAY(NO_GOOD_MESSAGE)
        }
    } ELSE {
        DISPLAY(NO_GOOD_MESSAGE)
    }
} ELSE {
    DISPLAY(NO_GOOD_MESSAGE)
}
```

A nested IF can be considered as AND condition as a condition.
So by summarizing the question message and its response part into a function, it is possible to write as follows.

```
IF(FUNC1() == TRUE AND FUNC2() == TRUE AND FUNC3() == TRUE){//Function call proceeds from left to right (Shortcut evaluated)
    DISPLAY(GOOD_MESSAGE)
} ELSE {
    DISPLAY(NO_GOOD_MESSAGE)
}
```

As an example, you can write concretely as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char YN(const char *prompt);
    int enter_age(const char *prompt);

    if(YN("Do you like beers Enter Y or N: \n") == 'Y' &&
       YN("Are you old enough to have a beer?\n") == 'Y' &&
       enter_age("How old are you?\n") >= 20){
        printf("\nLet's go for some beers, I will take the first round.\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nSorry my friend, maybe next time.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

char YN(const char *prompt){
    char ans[2], ret, ch;
    int ret_scnf;

    while(1){
        fputs(prompt, stdout);
        if((ret_scnf = scanf(" %1[YNyn]%c", ans, &ch)) == 2 && ch == '\n'){
            if(*ans == 'Y' || *ans == 'y'){
                ret = 'Y';
                break;
            } else if(*ans == 'N' || *ans == 'n'){
                ret = 'N';
                break;
            }
        } else if(ret_scnf == EOF){
                ret = 'N';
                break;
        }
        scanf("%*[^\n]");scanf("%*c");//clear input
    }
    return ret;
}
int enter_age(const char *prompt){
    int ret_scnf, age;
    char ch;

    while(1){
        fputs(prompt, stdout);
        if((ret_scnf = scanf("%d%c", &age, &ch)) == 2 && ch == '\n'){
            if(age < 0)//Can I enter years old at the age of 0?
                continue;
            return age;
        } else if(ret_scnf == EOF){
                age = -1;
                break;
        }
        scanf("%*[^\n]");scanf("%*c");
    }
    return age;
}
```