# How to use conditions with numbers and words

Tags: c

I've been trying to make this simple program that basically a little conversation. The biggest problem I've run into is that whenever I wanted to ask for the age and if someone wrongly answered with something that it's not a number, but a phrase or a word, instead of it beeing impossible it just assume a value. What can I write so that if someone rights something that is not a number it just repeats the loop?

```
    main (){
        printf("Can you tell me your age\n");
        scanf("%d",&age );
        do{
          if ( age < 16) {
            printf("You're a child!\n");
          }
          else if ( age == 17){
            printf("Me too, cool! Let's meet.\n");
          }
          else {
            printf("Pretty old! You are dying.\n");
          }
        } while ((age<=0) && (age>130));
    }
```

Comment: like `enter_age` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45888256/971127) ?

Comment: I doubt there's a number that is less than or equal to zero and greater than 130 at the same time. Maybe you meant to use `||`.

Comment: "it just assume a value" and "it just repeats the loop" are different behaviors. "If someone wrongly answered with something that it's not a number, but a phrase or a word" which should it do, "assume a value" (i.e. `age = 10; // default), or "repeat the loop" until a valid number for age value is entered?

Comment: Shouldn't it be obvious that the first step to debugging is to actually print out the value that you're getting? And the return value of scanf() for that matter? Why are you asking us to guess when you could just find out?

Answer (score 0):

To check if a character represents a digit or not, you can use the standard function `isdigit()`.
But in your case with `scanf()` you can just check for its return value.
You might want to "clean stdin" if you don't know what the user will type.

```
void    clean_stdin(void)
{
    int     c = 0;

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int     main(void)
{
    int     age;
    int     scanf_ret;

    do
    {
        printf("Can you tell me your age\n");
        scanf_ret = scanf("%d", &age);
        clean_stdin();

    } while (scanf_ret != 1);

    /*
        Now we know that age contains a valid number
    */

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `isgit` is not that helpful to check if a string represents a number. Hint: *number* is not the same thing as *digit*. Don't get them confused/mixed-up

Comment: @bolov You're right I'll be more careful next time. I mentionned `isdigit()` because it can be interesting for the OP I think  :)

Answer (score 0):

On success, [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. We've got only one argument, so we can use this return value in the `while` loop to continually check it against `1` (a valid input):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int age, temp, status;

    printf("Can you tell me your age\n");

    status = scanf("%d", &age);

    while(status!=1) {
        while( (temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n' ) {};
        printf("Invalid input... please enter a number: ");
        status = scanf("%d", &age);
    }
    if ( age < 16) {
        printf("You're a child!\n");
    }
    else if ( age == 17) {
      printf("Me too, cool! Let's meet.\n");
    }
    else {
      printf("Pretty old! You are dying.\n");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check what `scanf` is returning in the if statement,you can modify you code like this:

```
 int main()
  {
    int age;  

    printf("Can you tell me your age\n");

    scan:
    if((scanf("%d",&age ))==1)
{
    do{
      if ( age < 16) {
        printf("You're a child!\n");
      }
      else if ( age == 17){
        printf("Me too, cool! Let's meet.\n");
      }
      else {
        printf("Pretty old! You are dying.\n");
      }
    } while ((age<=0) && (age>130));
}
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter a number\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        goto scan;
    }           
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Careful, `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior  :(

Comment: First principle of dating: check the return value!